# Support for RetyPolicy in Azure Table Storage for WindowsAzure.Storage SDK version 7.0.0.0

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-sdk-.net

I need to apply custom retry policy for all Table Operations. This is what I have been using:

```
_account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(PhoenixConfiguration.AzureBlobStorageConnection);
var _tableClient = this._account.CreateCloudTableClient();
IRetryPolicy linearRetryPolicy = new LinearRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 10);
_tableClient.RetryPolicy = linearRetryPolicy;
```

I was using WindowsAzure.Storage SDK (version 6), after upgrading my project to use WindowsAzire.Storage SDK version 7, this code is breaking. What is the correct way to implement custom retry policy in the new SDK? Is there any documentation available that I can refer?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Compilation error. It seems that the RetryPolicy property is not supported in TableClient class anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your code is failing to compile is because `RetryPolicy` member on `CloudTableClient` was deprecated in version 6.0 and is now removed in 7.0 [What is surprising is that it is still there on `CloudBlobClient`, though it is deprecated].

In order to use `Retry Polcies`, you have to use `TableRequestOptions` and specify the retry policy there. For example, this is how you could use it when creating a table.

```
        var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
        IRetryPolicy linearRetry = new LinearRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 10);
        var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("MyTable");
        var tableRquestOptions = new TableRequestOptions()
        {
            RetryPolicy = linearRetry
        };
        table.CreateIfNotExists(tableRquestOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although RetryPolicy is still there is BlobClient, I am getting a strange error during runtime. My local emulator is throwing an error saying that the operation is not allowed.

Comment: Hmmm...I haven't tried it myself so I wouldn't know. But I would recommend going away from specifying retry polcies on the client object and specify at operation level as they may be taken away anytime.